# Mule 3: Setting a response timeout value for "http:rest-service-component"

Tags: mule

I have a flow that uses the `http:rest-service-component` component.  The URL that I want to call takes around a minute to return a response, but "http:rest-service-component" only waits for 10 seconds.

How do I change this timeout value?  The `http:rest-service-component` element doesn't have any sort of timeout attribute.  I also tried creating an "http:connector" and setting a timeout value there, but that didn't work.  Thanks.

```
<flow name="theFlow">
  <inbound-endpoint ... />
  <http:rest-service-component serviceUrl="..." />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're OK setting this time-out as a global value, here is how you would set it to 30 seconds:

```
<configuration defaultResponseTimeout="30000" />
```

This will affect all outbound endpoints of all transports though. If you would like to affect only this HTTP interaction, the only option I see consists in adding a `responseTimeout` query string parameter to the end of the `serviceUrl` attribute:

```
responseTimeout=30000
```

It *should* work but I haven't confirmed it.

Comment: Adding a "responseTimeout" query string parameter to the end of the URL worked.  Thanks.